# Bound for quantum adversary in CRYSTALS-Kyber

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, kyber

In [Kyber](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/634.pdf) the following estimation is given for a quantum adversary:

> **Theorem 4**. For any quantum adversary $A$ that makes at most $q_{RO}$ many queries to quantum random oracles $H$ and $G$, and at
> most $q_D$ many (classical) queries to the decryption oracle, there
> exists a quantum adversary $B$ such that
> $$\text{Adv}_{\text{Kyber}}^{\text{cca}}(A) \leq 8 q_{RO}^2 \cdot
>  \delta + 4q_{RO} \cdot
>  \sqrt{\text{Adv}_{\text{Kyber.CPA}}^{\text{pr}}(B)}$$

In accordance to @lamontap's comment, I have also found this estimation in [2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/604.pdf):

$$\text{Adv}_{\text{KEM}}^{\text{IND-CCA}}(B) \leq 8q_{RO} \left( \sqrt{q_{RO}^2 \cdot \delta + q_{RO} \cdot \sqrt{\text{Adv}_{\text{PKE}}^{\text{OW-CPA}}}} + q_{RO}\cdot \delta \right)$$

However, it remains open, how the exact way is to rewrite the double root, so that the result from Theorem 4 follows. I have not yet been able to find anything suitable in the reference [69](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1005.pdf) to rewrite the expression.

My question is therefore, how is the estimation in Theorem 4 actually created?

Comment: Note that the bound from the HHZ paper is as a function of the OW-PCA advantage, which is not the same as OW-CPA. The HHZ bound would actually lead to a double square root over the advantage of adversary B (see the very last page of their paper). The Kyber paper says they use ref [25] (the HHZ paper) for the correctness error. The main reduction seems to be done using the techniques of ref [69].